# postgresql random() bug?

Tags: postgresql, random

I have the following statement `select random() * 999 + 111 from generate_series(1,10)`

which results in:

```
690,046183290426
983,732229881454
1091,53674799064
659,380498787854
398,545482470188
775,65887248842
1044,79942638567
173,288027528208
584,690435883589
522,077123570256
```

as you see; Two values are over 999!

This one works fine:
`select random() * 9 + 1 from generate_series(1,10)`

My system is: PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

Is that a bug?

Comment: what a stupid: random() * (9999-1111) + 1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. The expression `random() * 999` gives you a number from `0` to `999` inclusive.

Adding one to that will give you a number `1` through `1000`. Adding `111` will give you a number `111` through `1110`. So, in addition to seeing some values over a thousand, you'll also see none under a hundred and eleven.

Your mistake appears to have been assuming that, when you use `999` instead of `9`, you have to add `111` instead of `1`. That's not the case. To get a number `1` through `1000`, you need:

```
random() * 999 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't a bug.

[`random`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html) generates a number in the range [0.0, 1.0]. Multiply this by 999, you get a number in the range [0.0, 999.0]. Add 111 and you have a number in the range [111.0, 1110.0].

In fact, given an even distribution by `random`, there's roughly a 11% chance of getting a number larger than 999. The result you're describing isn't only possible, it's expected.